# how can you get multiple inputs in c# on one line for example ( 1 2 3 4 5) without having to enter one by one

Tags: c#, input

can input one by one by pressing enter but im trying to have it read one on line separated by spaces.

```
 void readTestScores()
    {
        int i;
        double tests;

        Console.Write ("ENTER EXAM SCORE\t: ");
        exam = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write ("ENTER TEST SCORES\t: ");
        for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) 
        {
            tests = Convert.ToDouble (Console.ReadLine ());
            testavg += tests;
        }
        testavg /= 7;
        Console.WriteLine ("TEST AVERAGE IS\t\t: {0}",testavg);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Look into the string split method, as documented here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Usage would be to the effect of:

```
string s = Console.ReadLine();
double[] input = s.Split(' ').Select(t => Convert.ToDouble(t)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Sorry about that. Fixed.

Comment: im trying to enter all double not string

Comment: When you get the input you'll have to do a Double.Parse or preferable try parse.

Comment: You can use `double[] tests = Array.ConvertAll(s, new Converter<string,double>(Convert.ToDouble));`

Comment: Note that is you are going to insert that line directly, you need to leave out `double[]`, I just included it for clarity.